# How to get numbers between 2 keywords?

Tags: python, regex

First set of keywords:

```
boy = [car, gun, football]
```

Second set of keywords:

```
girl = [doll, clothes, dessert]
```

The string is

```
string = 'car~ $10.6 USD, doll>15.8-25.3 USD, gun10.8-15.7 USD'
```

How to find the numbers of the first set but not the second set from `string`?

For example, I want to get the price of `car` and `gun`, which are the keywords in the first set, then the result is `[10.6, 10.8-15.7]`

How to use regex to get it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this would be a lot easier if you split it into two parts. First parse the string to get all the `object, price` pairs, then filter the pairs you want from the ones you don't.

Comment: Can you show me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to locate the values and then form a dictionary:

```
import re 
string = 'car: $10.6 USD, doll: 15.8-25.3 USD, gun: 10.8-15.7 USD'
d = re.findall('\w+(?=:)|(?<=:\s)[^,]+', string)
new_d = {d[i]:d[i+1] for i in range(0, len(d), 2)}
boy = ['car', 'gun', 'football']
result = [new_d[i] for i in boy if i in new_d]
```

Output:

```
['$10.6 USD', '10.8-15.7 USD']
```

Edit: you can use `str.split` with `re.sub`:

```
new_result = [list(map(float, re.sub('\$|\sUSD', '', i).split('-'))) for i in result]
```

Output:

```
[[10.6], [10.8, 15.7]]
```

Edit: updated string:

```
string = 'car~ $10.6 USD, doll>15.8-25.3 USD, gun10.8-15.7 USD'
_d = dict(re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+|[\d\.\-]+', i) for i in string.split(', '))
d = {a:list(map(float, b.split('-'))) for a, b in _d.items()}
boy = ['car', 'gun', 'football']
result = [new_d[i] for i in boy if i in new_d]
```

Comment: Thank you, Ajax.My idea is first find all numbers followed by `USD`, then search forward from `USD` until find the keywords in the first set, then take those numbers in between. For example, we first find `[car: $10.6, gun: 10.8-15.7]`, the next step is getting [[10.6], [10.8, 15.7]]. The separator is not always `:`, sometimes there are no separators.